# Chrome browser unable to make a server call when print preview is opened

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, print-preview

I have a print preview page in which I open a page and execute print function after rendering a page. Firefox opens a popup for this and stalls the browser until we do some action cancel/print.
But the chrome browser open a left print panel which contains the options for the print.

The strange thing about this is when the page is in the preview, the parent application cannot make a server call. It will stop all the calls of the parent application until the print is done/cancelld.
I checked this behavior in GMAIL also, and it stalls that as well.
Ex, click print icon on a mail and it opens the print preview. Change tab to the gmail and try to open all the tabs. Some will work as server call is not there, but some like spam will not.

Also this happens only for the parent application and other tabs remain unaffected.

Can anyone figure out a workaround for this so that the print page does not know its parent and the print functionality works without stalling the main application.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted to google about this issue and as per them, we should be stopping the application from making an http call while the print preview page is open. They are not going to do anything about it. Plus, they mention that firefox also behaves in same manner, but it blocks the whole browser until you close the print option dialog box.

There was one more issue, that on dragging the print page to a new window, it used to hang the application, they didn't mention that they fixed that, but I was unable to reproduce that bug in the next chrome update.:)

Comment: We should be stopping the application from making calls?  That's absurd.  The reason why Firefox does this is because it uses the native print functionality, which auto blocks for us/them... because Google decided to incorporate their own Print Preview functionality, they should then be halting the user from going to another tab OR don't disallow XHR requests.

Comment: Yup, totally agree with you. They should try on blocking or fixing the issue in the next version.